# Unable to configure Java 11 to Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using windows and configured environment variables for Java 11. 
On the terminal, java version is 11 as expected and I am to compile and run Java class files via the terminal.

On Intellij (Community Version 2018.3.5), used to have version 8 which worked fine. I am not able to get it to work since changing to version 11 (tested with brand new projects too).

Under project Structure, file path is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11 as expected.

Under Project settings/ module, version set to 1.11 JDK. Unable to change language level to 11. Max level possible is 9.

For Default Project settings, unable to select any options for target bytecode version.

When I try to run the main method, which has nothing but a print statement, I get following error message:

> Error:Cannot run program "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   Community Edition 2017.3.3\jre64\bin\java" (in directory
>   "C:\Users\username.IdeaIC2017.3\system\compile-server"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Why is it looking at some weird space when my jdk path has been specified at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11 already?

Please advice what I am missing. Added some screen shots for reference.

UPDATE: My version is Community Version 2017.3.5. Refer to my comment below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you are saying that you use `2018.3.5`, but from the error message I see `2017`.
`Error:Cannot run program "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\jre64\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\username.IdeaIC2017.3\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Installed Community `2018.2.4` and I have jdk 10 available https://imgur.com/a/YeCf5me . Works on EAP `2018.3`. I think it has to do with your current settings

Comment: @sfat Oversight from me. Been always keeping Intellij up to date (most recently updated yesterday) or so I thought. Seems if you have a 2017 version.. it doesn't carry on to update to 2018 versions.. My version was 2017.3.5. Reinstalled 2018 version and it is working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: I added the answer for posterity if someone else bumps into the same issue. Glad you solved you problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2018.3.4` works fine for jdk > 1.8

[image]

The problem you are having is because of the settings that are being used

> Error:Cannot run program "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   Community Edition 2017.3.3\jre64\bin\java" (in directory
>   "C:\Users\username.IdeaIC2017.3\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess
>   error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Reinstalling and not reusing the same settings from 2017 should work fine.